# Mysqldump works but not mysql client

Tags: permissions, mysql, connection, mysqldump

How is that possible that on the same system I can use mysqldump but not mysql?
While mysqldump works fine, the mysqlclient says, root user access is denied. Explicit parameter to connect to the socket does not help either.

How to assess this problem further?

Comment: Please show the exact commands you are using and how they fail. Also, tell us about your operating system and which version of MySQL you have running, and which users you have added.

Answer (score 1):

I have forgotten to use "-p" option.